# Grails + BlazeDS Plugin

Tags: grails, blazeds, grails-plugin

We are currently using your BlazeDS plugin in our grails application.

We have encountered an issue whereby a null pointer exception being thrown in the class BlazedsOpenSessionInViewFilter is rapidly filling up our log files

The error message from our logs is as follows

```
[TP-Processor26] ERROR [/].[grails]  - Servlet.service() for servlet grails threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at grails.plugin.blazeds.BlazedsOpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(BlazedsOpenSessionInViewFilter.java:65)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

We are running on Tomcat 6 and this NullPointerException is rapidly filling up the log files.
I was thinking we could create our own version of the filter which catches this exception and update the appropriate section of BlazedsGrailsPlugin.groovy within the plugin
Would anyone see any issues with a dev team updating any portion of a third party plugin?
If anyone has any other suggestions for resolving this issue, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pushing the fix to this item up onto GIT and not hearing back from the owner, I decided to just fix the plugin locally for myself and now all is workined